# Adding short and int value, storing it in short variable

Tags: java

when i execute the below code, i got -7615.
Could anyone explain me how.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    short s = 1;
    int z=123456;
    s+=z;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: What is the range of values that can be stored in a short? And what do you expect the value to be if not -7615?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [JLS 5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> **short:** The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

```
int z=123456;
s+=z;
```

its same  as

```
 s = (short)(123456 + 1) ;
```

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

So 123457 = 11110001001000001
Short can represent by 16 bit = 1110001001000001 which is negative because its start with `1`

So to store -ve number convert it into two complement

1110001001000001 =2's complement `-7615.`

Answer (score 2):

`short` can't represent the value 123457 and thus you'll get an overflow.

123457 in binary would be `11110001001000001` i.e. 17 bits and since short can only store 16 bits the value will be truncated to `1110001001000001`. The first bit represents the sign, i.e. since it is `1` you have a negative number and since negative numbers are store in 2's complement `1110001001000001` represents the value of -7615 (positive 7615 would be binary `001110110111111` which is two's complement of `110001001000001` for negative 7615).